# R: agrupar en rangos los valores de un dataframe

Tags: r

Teniendo en cuenta un dataframe como esta:

```
 a$ID<-data.frame(c("PV001","PV001","PV002","PV002","PV003","PV003"))
 b$freq<-data.frame(c("468","487","213896","212005","90827","86592"))

 c<-cbind(a,b);colnames(c)<-c("ID","freq")
```

Quería saber como poder agrupar los datos acorde con el valor de ID y hacer un rango de los valores de freq.

Gracias de antemano,
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base puedes resolverlo mediante `aggregate()`. Voy a modificar tu ejemplo ya que así como estaría `c` no sería un `data.frame`:

```
c <- data.frame(ID=c("PV001","PV001","PV002","PV002","PV003","PV003"),
                 Freq=c("468","487","213896","212005","90827","86592"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

aggregate(Freq ~ ID, c, range)

     ID Freq.1 Freq.2
1 PV001    468    487
2 PV002 212005 213896
3 PV003  86592  90827
```

Notas:

- Podemos usar la notación de formula `Freq ~ ID` es decir la frecuencia en función del `ID`, el siguiente parámetro es el `data.frame` a agrupar
- Por último, aplicamos la función `range()` a cada grupo de `ID`

Comment: Perfecto, funciona la función!